# MSBuild Duration

Tags: performance, msbuild

I have a solution with around 1000 projects and the build duration total is around 4 and a half minutes.

I want to be able to diagnose what that 4 and a half minutes is spent doing to try and establish if the build process can be optimised.

Is there a way to get this sort of information?

EDIT: this is always on a clean checkout, so a full build (not rebuild) will always occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/ds` (`/detailedsummary`) option of `MSBuild CLI`.

`/ds`:

> Show detailed information at the end of the build log about the
>   configurations that were built and how they were scheduled to nodes.

Example output:

```
         Detailed Build Summary
======================
============================== Build Hierarchy (IDs represent configurations) =====================================================
Id                  : Exclusive Time   Total Time   Path (Targets)
———————————————————————————————————————————–
0                   : 0.036s           0.295s       F:BugsMultiProccir1.proj (ParallelBuild)
| 1                 : 0.047s           0.047s       F:BugsMultiProccir2.proj ()
| 3                 : 0.209s           0.209s       F:BugsMultiProccir4.proj ()
| 2                 : 0.210s           0.210s       F:BugsMultiProccir3.proj ()
| 4                 : 0.212s           0.217s       F:BugsMultiProccir5.proj ()
| | 10              : 0.005s           0.005s       F:BugsMultiProccir8.proj ()
| . 11              : 0.003s           0.003s       F:BugsMultiProccir9.proj ()
| 5                 : 0.001s           0.001s       F:BugsMultiProccir6.proj ()
. 6                 : 0.003s           0.015s       F:BugsMultiProccir7.proj ()
| . 7               : 0.004s           0.012s       F:BugsMultiProccir5.proj ()
| | | 8             : 0.007s           0.007s       F:BugsMultiProccir8.proj ()
| | . 9             : 0.001s           0.001s       F:BugsMultiProccir9.proj ()
============================== Node Utilization (IDs represent configurations) ====================================================
Timestamp:            1       2       3       4        Duration   Cumulative
———————————————————————————————————————————–
634032540333349050:   0       x       x       x        0.035s     0.035s
634032540333699050:   1       x       x       x        0.041s     0.076s
634032540334109050:   |       4       2       3        0.006s     0.082s
634032540334169050:   5       |       |       |        0.001s     0.083s
634032540334179050:   6       |       |       |        0.002s     0.085s
634032540334199050:   7       |       |       |        0.002s     0.087s
634032540334219050:   8       |       |       |        0.007s     0.094s
634032540334289050:   9       |       |       |        0.001s     0.095s
634032540334299050:   7       |       |       |        0.002s     0.097s
634032540334319050:   6       |       |       |        0.001s     0.098s
634032540334329050:   x       |       |       |        0.188s     0.286s ###
634032540336209050:   x       x       10      11       0.003s     0.289s
634032540336239050:   x       x       |       x        0.002s     0.291s
634032540336259050:   x       4       x       x        0.003s     0.294s
634032540336289050:   0       x       x       x        0.002s     0.296s
———————————————————————————————————————————–
Utilization:          33.8    96.8    97.7    96.8     Average Utilization: 81.3
```

[MSBuild 4 Detailed Build Summary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/03/05/msbuild-4-detailed-build-summary/)

---

Or you can try set `/verbosity:diag` - [MSBuildVerbosity](https://fake.build/apidocs/fake-msbuildhelper-msbuildverbosity.html). After build at end of log you get the same results. My example log *is not full*, because it has personality information.

```
  ============================== Node Utilization (IDs represent configurations) ====================================================
  Timestamp:            1        Duration   Cumulative
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (TaskId:0)
  636605029034003906:   0        0,278s     0,278s ##### (TaskId:0)
  636605029036787109:   1        2,406s     2,685s ################################################ (TaskId:0)
  636605029060849609:   4        0,874s     3,559s ################# (TaskId:0)
  636605029069589843:   5        0,796s     4,354s ############### (TaskId:0)
  636605029077548828:   1        0,235s     4,590s #### (TaskId:0)
  636605029079902343:   3        6,171s     10,761s ########################################################################################################################### (TaskId:0)
  636605029141611328:   2        0,854s     11,614s ################# (TaskId:0)
  636605029150146484:   6        2,154s     13,769s ########################################### (TaskId:0)
  636605029171689453:   2        8,570s     22,339s ########################################################################################################################################################################### (TaskId:0)
  636605029257392578:   1        0,006s     22,345s  (TaskId:0)
  636605029257451171:   7        4,986s     27,331s ################################################################################################### (TaskId:0)
  636605029307314453:   1        14,229s     41,560s ############################################################################################################################################################################################################
################################################################################ (TaskId:0)
  636605029449599609:   0        0,003s     41,563s  (TaskId:0)
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Utilization:          100,0    Average Utilization: 100,0 (TaskId:0)
```

---

```
Target Performance Summary:
        0 ms  PrepareResources                           3 calls
        0 ms  SetWin32ManifestProperties                 3 calls
        0 ms  ResGen                                     3 calls
        0 ms  AfterResGen                                3 calls
        0 ms  CreateSatelliteAssemblies                  3 calls
        0 ms  BeforeResGen                               3 calls
        0 ms  PrepareResourceNames                       3 calls
        0 ms  CreateCustomManifestResourceNames          3 calls
        0 ms  ComputeIntermediateSatelliteAssemblies     1 calls
        0 ms  GetTargetPath                              3 calls
        0 ms  Compile                                    3 calls
        0 ms  AfterMarkupCompilePass1                    3 calls
        0 ms  ResolveReferences                          3 calls
        0 ms  BeforeCompile                              3 calls
        0 ms  _CopySourceItemsToOutputDirectory          3 calls
        0 ms  PrepareForRun                              3 calls
        0 ms  AfterResolveReferences                     3 calls
        0 ms  PrepareProjectReferences                   3 calls
        0 ms  ValidateToolsVersions                      1 calls
        0 ms  ValidateProjects                           1 calls
        0 ms  GetNativeManifest                          2 calls
        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                3 calls
        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          3 calls
        0 ms  _AfterCompileWinFXInternal                 3 calls
        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  3 calls
        0 ms  BeforeResolveReferences                    3 calls
        0 ms  AfterCompileWinFX                          3 calls
        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 3 calls
        0 ms  AfterCompile                               3 calls
        1 ms  GetTargetFrameworks                        2 calls
        1 ms  ExpandSDKReferences                        3 calls
        2 ms  _BeforeVBCSCoreCompile                     3 calls
        2 ms  GenerateSatelliteAssemblies                1 calls
        2 ms  ExpressionBuildExtension                   3 calls
        2 ms  ValidationExtension                        3 calls
        3 ms  _CheckForCompileOutputs                    3 calls
        3 ms  FileClassification                         3 calls
        5 ms  CopySilverlightApplications                1 calls
        6 ms  _CopyAppConfigFile                         1 calls
        9 ms  ResolveKeySource                           3 calls
       13 ms  PrepareForBuild                            3 calls
       14 ms  _SetEmbeddedWin32ManifestProperties        3 calls
       17 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     3 calls
       20 ms  GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute    3 calls
       25 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryXamlAppDefs        3 calls
       34 ms  _GenerateCompileInputs                     3 calls
       35 ms  GetFrameworkPaths                          3 calls
       38 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 3 calls
       45 ms  CleanXsdCodeGen                            3 calls
       55 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                 3 calls
       56 ms  PreXsdCodeGen                              3 calls
       58 ms  _SetTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute        3 calls
       62 ms  GetTargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker     3 calls
       66 ms  CoreCompile                                3 calls
       66 ms  _GenerateSatelliteAssemblyInputs           3 calls
       71 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  3 calls
       76 ms  ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades          3 calls
       81 ms  ValidateSolutionConfiguration              1 calls
       82 ms  GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems              3 calls
       88 ms  CopyFilesToOutputDirectory                 3 calls
       97 ms  ResolveSDKReferences                       3 calls
      105 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   3 calls
      611 ms  SplitResourcesByCulture                    3 calls
      642 ms  CreateManifestResourceNames                1 calls
      798 ms  ResolveNuGetPackageAssets                  2 calls
     1008 ms  FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences       3 calls
     1177 ms  _BuiltWebOutputGroupOutput                 1 calls
     1249 ms  CoreResGen                                 3 calls
     1632 ms  IncrementalClean                           3 calls
     1659 ms  _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal                  2 calls
     1984 ms  _HandlePackageFileConflicts                3 calls
     2005 ms  _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties   3 calls
     2292 ms  AssignTargetPaths                          3 calls
     3007 ms  _GenerateCompileDependencyCache            3 calls
     4538 ms  ResolveAssemblyReferences                  3 calls
     6253 ms  _CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites         3 calls
    25037 ms  ResolveProjectReferences                   3 calls
    41369 ms  Build                                      4 calls

Task Performance Summary:
        3 ms  FindAppConfigFile                          2 calls
        6 ms  MakeDir                                    3 calls
        7 ms  ResolveKeySource                           3 calls
        7 ms  WriteLinesToFile                           3 calls
        7 ms  Touch                                      2 calls
        8 ms  GetFrameworkPath                           3 calls
       12 ms  GetReferenceAssemblyPaths                  3 calls
       27 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 3 calls
       35 ms  Message                                   10 calls
       42 ms  Delete                                     6 calls
       52 ms  CallTarget                                 3 calls
       55 ms  ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet                 3 calls
       99 ms  GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask     2 calls
      128 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          3 calls
      163 ms  AssignCulture                              3 calls
      300 ms  CreateCSharpManifestResourceName           2 calls
      463 ms  ResolveNuGetPackageAssets                  2 calls
      590 ms  GenerateResource                           1 calls
     1007 ms  ResolvePackageFileConflicts                3 calls
     1177 ms  CreateItem                                 3 calls
     1498 ms  Hash                                       3 calls
     1661 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      3 calls
     1712 ms  Copy                                       9 calls
     2040 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           6 calls
     2104 ms  AssignTargetPath                          18 calls
     2583 ms  FindUnderPath                             15 calls
     4530 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   3 calls
    68091 ms  MSBuild   

                            10 calls
```

Comment: I'm having troubles getting this flag used as I use a framework to call MSBuild, will update when I have it working 

Comment: @BlythMeister,  `a framework to call MSBuild` What you mean? You launches build through MSBuild C# task?

Comment: We use FAKE for build scripts, the msbuild helper doesn't support the ds flag.  I need to get it added.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed. Kirill Osenkov wrote two very helpful [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2015/05/12/msbuild-unnecessary-rebuilds-because-of-generated-assemblyattributes-cs/) [posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2014/08/04/how-to-investigate-rebuilding-in-visual-studio-when-nothing-has-changed/) on the very subject.

You should try following the steps listed in them to get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: I know that this will never do a rebuild as it's always a clean checkout of the repository.  I more want to establish where time is spent.